# Extract words between the first occurrence two strings in a sentence

Tags: r, regex

I have the following input sentence:

```
B <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] ASSIGNOR"
```

I want to extract the words between the first occurrence of `AND` (should be included in the output) and `ASSIGNOR` (should be excluded from the output).

*Expected Output*

```
AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635]".
```

I have a lot more word before assignee and after assignor. I just want to captured the middle one as shown above.

Here is my so far trial which didn't produce the required output:

```
sub(".*ASSIGNEE.* *(AND.*?) *ASSIGNOR.*", "\\1", B)
# [1] "AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635]"
```

Thank you.

Comment: With a modification of your code, should work.Try `sub(".*ASSIGNEE.* *(AND.*?ASSIGNOR).*", "\\1", B)`

Comment: How to detect the first and in sentence? This code detect the last and

Comment: I am not sure what you want to get, but if I am not wrong, try `sub(".*ASSIGNEE.*? *(AND.*?ASSIGNOR).*", "\\1", B)`. That is,in your code you have to close the parenthesis after ASSIGNOR if you want to include it (as in my first comment) and you have to add a `?` after `ASSIGNEE.*` to get the first `AND`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `stringr` and `regex`:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(B, regex("(?=AND)(?s)(.*$)"))

# [1] " AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] ASSIGNOR"
```

For a regex expression reference have a look [Regular Expression Reference: Special Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

## Update

If you want words between `AND` `ASSIGNOR` you can modify the `regex` as follows:

```r
str_extract(B, regex("(?=AND)(.*?)(?=ASSIGNOR)"))

B <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND ASSIGNOR"
# "AND "

B <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND The Man in the iron mask other more strings ASSIGNOR"
#AND The Man in the iron mask other more strings

B <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ASSIGNOR ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] ASSIGNOR and another ASSIGNOR"
#"AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN 

B <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] ASSIGNOR and another ASSIGNOR"

#"AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] "
```

This should work now.

Comment: I dont want the word assignor. I have alot of words after assignor. I dont want to extract all after assignor

Comment: @Wawa See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the string you need with a base R solution using `regexec` / `regmatches`:

```
rx <- "\\b(AND.*?)\\s*ASSIGNOR\\b"
x <- "ASSIGNEE/BANK (FORMERLY KNOWN AS BANK SETIA) AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635] ASSIGNOR"
regmatches(x, regexec(rx, x))[[1]][2]
## => [1] "AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635]"
```

The same regex with the `ASSIGNOR` moved into a lookahead can be used with a PCRE regex:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\bAND.*?(?=\\s*ASSIGNOR\\b)", x, perl=TRUE))
# => [1] "AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635]"
```

The same regex with the `ASSIGNOR` moved into a lookahead can be used with a `stringr::str_extract` function that uses the ICU regex library:

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(x, "\\bAND.*?(?=\\s*ASSIGNOR\\b)")
# => [1] "AND NUR AMIRA BINTI RAMZI [NRIC NO. 918267-16-6252] AND HAFIZUDDIN BIN ALI [NRIC NO. 918273-16-1635]"
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(AND.*?)` - Capturing group 1: `AND` and then any amount of any 0+ chars (in a PCRE and ICU regexps, other than line break chars) as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `ASSIGNOR\b` - whole word `ASSIGNOR`.

In the PCRE and ICU regexps there is no need for the capturing parentheses and the `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that matches the text but does not put it into the match (=does  not consume the text).

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Ocl5yT/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
and{1}.*
```

This regex will find the first "and" and match with that and the continue until a newline. If you want the entire string you can do something like this (there is probably a better way to do this.

```
and{1}[^]*
```

You can test the regex on this site: https://regexr.com/

Comment: I can't use this comment it still detect the last and

Answer (score 0):

you can try it. First group is what you want to get.

```
/^.*?(and.*?)(?=and|$)/i
```

You can test the regex on this site: https://regex101.com/r/jNVQLT/1